# How could Slick betray the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In the early episode "The Hidden Enemy", the clone trooper Slick, spies on the Army of the Republic, using the justification that his brothers were "cannon fodder", while the Jedi easily survived battles.
However, this seems to contradict "Attack of the Clones". The Kaminoans tell Obi-Wan that the clones are completely obedient.

Comment: Yes, I know the clones questioned orders in the Umbara arc. However, in that instance, the clones eventually discovered they were fighting each other.

Comment: Not really fleshed out as an in-universe answer, but complete obedience is not a thing people can guarantee, from other people, it's just not how people-ness works.  With that in mind, I'd guess they were... well, advertising...I mean basically overselling their "product" and not minding inaccuracies in what is, to them, a business deal.

Comment: Perhaps he had a malfunction with his inhibitor chip or some other defect in the cloning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are right, clones in *Clone Wars* cartoon are different then clones in the movies. In the movies we don't see them as anything more then "human droids" , they simply follow orders without sense of wrong or right. For  *Clone Wars* they have been completely humanized- they have their own individual personalities, emotions and opinions. For example, [Slick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Slick) did what he did because he considered Jedi incompetent military commanders (which is true, because they didn't have the training or experience in military matters). To explain the clones' blind obedience in carrying out Order 66, [Inhibitor chips](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Control_chip) were introduced.

What about complete obedience promised by Kaminoans? In universe, this could be explained by the fact that [Kaminoans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kaminoan) never had a project of this size before, and considered clone troopers as the pinnacle of their achievement, yet they were too aloft to consider that their "work" could somehow become independent from them. This was shown in episode [Conspiracy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conspiracy) and [Fugitive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fugitive), where Kaminoans clearly state that clones "belong to them", i.e only they understand their behavior.